# Entity scope parameter: objectName is invalid:

Tags: partner-communities, production, summer-18

When i moved community to production and trying to access the one of the header tab than i am getting an error saying "Entity scope parameter: objectName is invalid:", when i tried to look around it, I found this has been fixed in summer'18 release. But i am still getting the same error.Can anybody please help me out here.

Comment: I am able to fix this issue, by providing the license access to the specific logged in User as the object was part of managed package from installed app.

Answer (score 1):

For object name, you need to enter the API name of the object. The name of my object is Market Report, I was trying things like "market-report" and "market_report". "Market_Report__c" did the trick. Hope this helps.

Comment: Travis, to make it clearer that your answer has a definitive solution for future browsers, you might remove the first paragraph (we habitually remove answers that don't provide a solution). Welcome to SFSE!